# PHP Object in SQL Select Query

Tags: php, mysql, soap

Here is my web service call.

Right now, it's hard coded, but I will stick it behind a User Form.

It's returning an object. How do I use that object with a SQL query? I need to do various Select queries with Products, Manufacturers, in the WHERE criteria I need the contract vehicle ID.

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Call to Navigator Web Service</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<?php    


$param = array('commodity' => 'LAPTOP',  'placeOfPerformance' => array('location' => 'LSA' , 'lsaStates' => 'NY', 'VA', 'TX', 'oconusStates' => 'ALASKA', 'EMEA'),  'equipmentType' => 'ANY', 'socioEconomicObjective' => 'NONE', 'agencyCode' => '007',);

$client = new SoapClient('https://sso-test.fas.gsa.gov/mpdev/navigator/wsdl');  
$results = $client->__soapCall('retrieveContractVehicles', array('parameters' => $param));  

print_r($results);  
echo ("<br />");
echo ("End of line");

?>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class test_object
{
    public $contractVehicle = array(
        0=>'ITSchedule70',
        1=>'ITCommodityProgram'
);

    function get_contract()
    {
        return $this->contractVehicle;
    }
}

$var = new test_object(); //let us say this is the part you are getting the result from web service
echo $var->contractVehicle[0]; //this is how you will get ITSchedule70
```

result:

ITSchedule70

what do you mean by *How to insert a query? Do you mean how to save it?* I am not sure about the question, but this is how I will insert a query(save to the database)

```
<?php 
define('DB_IP','');             //this is your server's IP/name
define('DB_USERNAME','');       //database username
define('DB_PASSWORD','');       //database password
define('DB_DATABASE','');       //default database to use

class test_object   //I do not have the webservice object so I just add this
{
    public $contractVehicle = array(
        0=>'ITSchedule70',
        1=>'ITCommodityProgram'
    );

    function get_contract()
    {
        return $this->contractVehicle;
    }
}

$var = new test_object(); //lets say this is the variable you will save the result when you invoke the webservice


try
{
    //check for connection
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_IP,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

    if(!$connection)
    {
        $db_conn_err = "Unable to Connect to Database ERROR: ". mysqli_connect_error($connection);

        throw new Exception($db_conn_err);
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}




$qry_trans = "INSERT INTO `Product`
                            (
                                `id`,
                                `other_column`,
                                `ContractVehicle`
                            )
                            VALUES
                            (
                                1,                              //use your own value depending on  your table requirements
                                'use your own values',
                                $var->contractVehicle[0]        //ITSchedule70
                            );";

try
{
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $qry_trans );   //execute the query

    if( $result )
    {
        echo 'Successfully saved!';
    }
    else
    {
        $err = 'Unable to insert into table err:'.mysqli_error($connection).'<br>';
        throw new Exception($err);  
    }

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

**UPDATE BASED ON YOUR COMMENT**

If the data changes, you might want to know which index in the webservice you want to find,

```
echo $var->contractVehicle[2];    //will return OtherContractVehicle
```

you might want to clarify your question or atleast post your sample data so that I can analyse it more.

Comment: Ok, I will study this over.  Thanks.  To clarify another goal: the response from the web service will obviously change. So the SQL query should have some variable or global variable, right so we don't have to always rewrite the query.

Comment: More clarification:
 
Evertime the user submits the form, I'm making a call to the web service. So it might return 0=>'ITSchedule70'  or   1=>'ITCommodityProgram'  or   2=>'OtherContractVehicle'
 
I've got 4 contract vehicles.
 
Based on that returned contract vehicle, I need to use that as a WHERE criteria to return results from a Products table.
 
So like:
 
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `contact_vehicle_id` = 2
 
So the important point is the WHERE needs to be dynamic, because on the fly.

Comment: I revised my question for better clarity. Please consider.

Comment: Forgot to mention in the last post, for prototyp purposes I obviously, hard coded the values. 

But on production it will be a user form.